# UrlRewriting.Net not working even with a simple rewrite

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, iis-7, url-rewriting, iis-6

I want to make URL rewriting using [UrlRewriteNet](http://urlrewriting.net/160/en/documentation.html) module.

While I have added all the required config settings, nothing seems to take action even for simple rewrite.

web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <!-- URL Rewriting.NET -->
        <section name="urlrewritingnet"
            restartOnExternalChanges="true"
            requirePermission="false"
            type="UrlRewritingNet.Configuration.UrlRewriteSection, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter" />
    </configSections>
    <system.web>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="UrlRewriteModule" type="UrlRewritingNet.Web.UrlRewriteModule, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter"/>
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <remove name="UrlRewriteModule"/>
            <add name="UrlRewriteModule" type="UrlRewritingNet.Web.UrlRewriteModule, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
    <urlrewritingnet
        xmlns="http://www.urlrewriting.net/schema/config/2006/07">
        <rewrites>
            <add name="GeneralRewrite"
                virtualUrl="^~/Default.aspx"
                rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
                destinationUrl="~/MyDefault.aspx"
                ignoreCase="true"
            />
        </rewrites>
    </urlrewritingnet>
</configuration>
```

Nothing more is requires as far as I understand to just rewrite the Deafault.aspx page to MyDefault.aspx. So I would expect my URL from https://server.address/Project.SiteName/Default.aspx to simply become https://server.address/Project.SiteName/MyDefault.aspx.

I use development in my local IIS 7 Windows 7 development pc but the release production server will be IIS 6 thats why I included both configuration into the web.config.

Unfortunately, and where there is no error for any reason, checked the IIS and saw that the module is registered in Modules section but the engine never runs !

Is there something that I miss here?

Comment: Do you actually have a page called MyDefault.aspx? What that rule says is if someone enters the URL Default.aspx (assuming this page does not exist) then it will map to MyDefault.aspx - the URL will stay the same.

Comment: What I need to do Kevin actually is, when this user enters the URL Default.aspx to show in address bar MyDefault.aspx. It seems that I'm missing something.....can you provide a rule for the desired rewrite I need?

Comment: This is not how URL rewriting works - the point is you may have a messy URL like default.aspx?q1=variable which is hard for a user to remember and type so instead you can create a rewrite rule which allows them to enter /variable/MyFriendlyName.aspx the rewrite rule maps this back to the first URL so the page is correclty rendered but the URL the user sees does not change

Comment: In your case why not just create MyDefault.aspx as a physical page and move all the functionality into it and then in Default.aspx just have a Response.Redirect("MyDefault.aspx")

Comment: OK, I misunderstood URL Rewriting for my case, I understand what you say and I have it well in my mind, this kind of rewriting is when you already defined the querystring parameters or currently developing the app, which is really helpful and nice, is there any way I could change my already going to production web site app the way I mentioned? Without going and figuring all the parameters for all pages which many could be added dynamically from behind code?!

Answer (score 3):

make the above in following manner

```
 <configuration>
     <configSections>
     <section name="urlrewritingnet"
     restartOnExternalChanges="true"
     requirePermission ="false"
     type="UrlRewritingNet.Configuration.UrlRewriteSection,
     UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter" />
     </configSections>
 </configuration>
```

then comes the rewriting sections to rewrite urls

```
  <urlrewritingnet>
   <rewrites>
```

your urls to rewite will mapped here.....

```
    </rewrites>
   </urlrewritingnet>
```

and finally need to http module which will listen to the requests.

```
<system.web>
  <httpModules>
  <add name="UrlRewriteModule"
  type="UrlRewritingNet.Web.UrlRewriteModule, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter" />
  </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

Except this no configuration needs to done in web.config just reference the dll (mandatory)
and .xsd file for intellisense 
http://blog.vizioz.com/2009/11/add-intellisense-when-using-url.html

Answer (score 0):

Open Web.config and add modules

```
<configuration>
<system.webserver> 

<modules>

<add name="UrlRewriteModule" type="UrlRewritingNet.Web.UrlRewriteModule, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter"/>
<remove name="Session"/>
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>

</modules>

</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```